# How can I sort json date in my adapter and fragment class

Tags: android, date, sorting, kotlin

I want to sort json date and pass it to  my adapter in kotlin and fragment

below my date implementation in adapter class where I am formatting date I just stuck I dont know what to do

```
    class NewsAdapter(private val onClick: (Article) -> Unit): RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return differ.currentList.size
    }


    private val differCallback = object: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Article>(){
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem

        }
    }
 var differ = AsyncListDiffer(this,differCallback)
    // update you data in recycler


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder {
        val itemBinding = inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return NewsViewHolder(itemBinding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var articleItems = differ.currentList[position]
        holder.bind(articleItems)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { onClick(articleItems) }

    }

    class NewsViewHolder(private val itemBinding: NewsItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemBinding.root) {
        fun bind(articles: Article) {
            itemBinding.articleDescription.text = articles.description
            itemBinding.articleTitle.text = articles.title
            articles.publishedAt.parseDate()?.let {
                itemBinding.articleDate.text = it.userFormat()
            }

            itemBinding.article = articles

        }

    }
```

}

below my Date extension

```
fun String.parseDate(): Date? {
    val df = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.US)
    return df.parse(this)
}

fun Date.userFormat(): String {
    val df = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US)
    return df.format(this)
}
```

below my Article.kt

```
@Parcelize

    data class Article(
        @SerializedName("author")
        val author: String,
        @SerializedName("content")
        val content: String,
        @SerializedName("description")
        val description: String,
        @SerializedName("publishedAt")
        val publishedAt: String,
        @SerializedName("source")
        val source: Source,
        @SerializedName("title")
        val title: String,
        @SerializedName("url")
        val url: String,
        @SerializedName("urlToImage")
        val urlToImage: String
) : Parcelable
```

below my BBCNewsViewModel.kt where I am implementing viewmodel

below my BBCNewsFragment.kt

```
class BBCNewsFragment : Fragment(R.layout.news_fragment) {

    private val viewModel by viewModel<BBCNewsViewModel>()
    private val adapter = NewsAdapter() { article ->
        findNavController().navigate(
            NewsFragmentDirections.actionNewsFragmentToDetailFragment(article)
        )
    }

    private var _binding: NewsFragmentBinding? = null

    // with the backing property of the kotlin we extract
    // the non null value of the _binding
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        _binding = NewsFragmentBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        //Add adapter in recyclerView
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        // listening new data
        viewModel.news.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { response ->
            adapter.differ.submitList(response.articles as MutableList<Article>)
        }

        viewModel.progress.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){  showLoading ->
            binding.progressBar.isVisible = showLoading
        }

    }
    }



class BBCNewsViewModel(private val useCase: BBCNewsResponseUseCase) : ViewModel() {


     var news= MutableLiveData<NewsResponse>()
    // Expose to the outside world

    // Expose to the outside world
    val error = MutableLiveData<String>()
    var progress = MutableLiveData(false)

init{
    getNews()
}
    private fun getNews() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
  progress.postValue(true)
            useCase.invoke()
                .fold({ newsResponse ->
                    news.postValue(newsResponse)
                }, {
                    error.postValue(it.message)
                })
            progress.postValue(false)
        }
    }




}
```

Comment: can you eloborate what you mean

Comment: Single responsibility principle applied to Adapter means the Adapter just displays the list of data that you send to it. So you should pass it data that is already sorted. You can call `sortedBy` on a list to get a sorted copy for use in your adapter.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I did not understand what you mean

Comment: okay how can sorted date in my extension class then

Comment: how can you explain with coding sample

Comment: I dont need long I need extension function where I want to implement inside extension function